# How we can install a site-wide 301 rel=canonical forward?

Tags: wordpress, redirect, http-headers, canonical-link

I have a wordpress site for example www.example.com and it has more than 300 pages. I have installed a copy of our entire www.example.com site on a subdomain of the US site. For example the subdomain is http://abc.tm.org/ and this subdomain contain all the contents of example.com

Now is there any way to redirect my whole example.com site to abc.tm.org site? I want to use 301 rel=canonical redirect. Otherwise google may bann my site for duplicate content.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, 301 and rel=canonical are two different things. If you want to just duplicate the site, not move it, just putting a canonical tag like:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.example.com/original-page-url/"/>
```

on the new abc.tm.org site will do the trick and stop google getting annoyed. It's basically telling Google "that's the original page, there's just this URL you're at now that points at it too". ...so no penalisation for duplicate content.

If you want to 301 the entire original site so users are redirected, you need to put a rule in your .htaccess / apache config. Something like this article says:
http://webdesign.about.com/od/mod_rewrite/qt/site_redirects.htm

Hope that helps!